# Python API Error - 'faultstring': 'JSONThreatProtection

Tags: python, api

First time trying to extract data via an API. I'm getting stuck with how to pass the raw data. I have been able to get it to work in postman but I can't quite figure it out with Python.

I've been getting this error:
`{'fault': {'faultstring': 'JSONThreatProtection[JSON-Threat-Protection-1]: Execution failed. reason: Expecting { or [ at line 1', 'detail': {'errorcode': 'steps.jsonthreatprotection.ExecutionFailed'}}}`

I'm pretty sure its the data portion that is wrong but I haven't been able to figure out if it's just a syntax error or something bigger that I'm missing.

My code as follows:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://url/customers/shipmentstatus"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }

data = {
    "Id": [
    "AZ1234"
  ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code posts the data as form encoded data, not as JSON. That's because you use the `data` parameter to supply the payload. To fix, encode the data as JSON using [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

But a better way is to pass the data to requests using the `json` parameter:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

Using the `json` parameter is easier and it will also add the `Content-Type: application/json` header for you.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Great! You can accept the answer if it has solved your problem.